# Uniqueness of polar decomposition of normal operator

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $T \in \mathcal{L}(H)$, a bounded linear operator. It is well-known that $T$ is normal if and only if there exist positive and unitary operators $P$ and $U$ such that
$$ 
T=UP=PU.
$$
It is also true that if $T$ is invertible, then the decomposition is unique (Rudin, "Functional Analysis", Th 12.35). I would like to ask: when is unique the positive operator $P$? And the unitary operator $U$? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $T=UP$ where $P \ge 0$ and $U$ is unitary, then $T^*T=P^2$; so $P$ is the unique positive square root of $T^*T$. $U$ is not determined on the orthogonal complement of the range of $P$.

Comment: And if Im(T) is dense, is U unique?

Comment: If $\mathcal{R}(T)$ is dense, then $\mathcal{N}(T^*)=\{0\}$, which implies that $\mathcal{N}(T)=\{0\}$ because $\|T^*x\|^2=\langle TT^*x,x\rangle=\langle T^*Tx,x\rangle=\|Tx\|^2$. Then $P=\sqrt{T^*T}$ has dense range, which uniquely determines $U$ from $T=UP$ because $U$ is determined on a dense subspace and is isometric.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot.